# install xcode plugin with lion

Tags: xcode, macos, plugins, osx-lion

I'm trying to install a plugin for Xcode but can't find the folder
/Users/myname/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode nor the folder /Users/myname/Library/Application Support/Developer

I don't know if I'm missing something (Xcode version 4.4)

Comment: As I understand it, plug-ins from Xcode 3 and earlier are not supported in Xcode 4, and the plug-in API for Xcode 4 is not published.

Answer (score 0):

Try this directory
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns